# How to determine when drag leaves the main application window. WPF

Tags: wpf

How can I determine when Drag, started by DragDrop.DoDragDrop function leaves the bounds of main application window. I tried to listen to MouseLeave event on main window but it doesn't work because mouse is captured by drag operation. I also tried DragLeave event but it is fired on each element within the window, not only when drag leaves main window. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Add a condition on the Drag Leave checking for the sender and check if the sender is the main window to get the drag leave events for Main Window Only.

Comment: Thanks for comment but sender (as well as e.Source and e.OriginalSource) are always point to some child controls which make impossible to track when is actually drag leave the window